# Using search engine friendly URLs

Tags: url, hyperlink, seo

My website will be using search engine friendly URLs made up from the subject line of postings by members. A subject could be how to create a class at runtime so the URL will be:

www.example.com/topic/how-to-create-a-class-at-runtime

Ok so that gets stored and hopefully spidered and listed in the search engines. The user can edit their posting at any time and they can also change their subject line.

My question is, if they change their subject line, should the old link still be active and a new one added to the database both pointing at the same article or should the link only be with the new subject line? If the latter I would have a lot of dead links from google etc if many users changed their subject line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [server-side redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_redirect) to redirect from the old URL(s) to the new URL.

In your example, you should use a [301 redirect ("Moved Permanently")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Comment: Yes that is what I intended to do so I would then end up with 2 or more valid links, one which would give a 200 header and the others 301. But... Is it good practice or do I just scrap the other links when the user changes subject and return 402? What I have seen done is www.example.com/12345-this-is-the-seo-friendly-part where the 12345 is the resource locator and the bit after that can be anything as my php code will only look at the 12345. That sounds like a better option.

Comment: @MikeC: I don’t understand what you mean with "scrap the other links". And I assume you don’t mean 402 (Payment Required), do you?